# Javascript Reverse Method Won't Reverse My Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I am trying to use the Javascript reverse() method and when I console log the array out after reversing it, it is still in the same order it was previously in. Here is my code:

```
var logos = <?php echo json_encode($logos); ?>;

var logoArray = logos.reverse();

console.log(logos);
console.log(logoArray);
```

I am getting the array from PHP and json encoding it. I am then taking that array and running the reverse() method to reverse the order of the array items. When I then console.log each array out they are identical, instead of the second array being reversed.

I can't seem to figure out what would be causing this issue?

Comment: What does `logos` look like?

Comment: please share the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reverse()` does mutate the array in place, therefore `logos` gets reversed. `logoArray` is just a reference to `logos`.

To get a different array and reverse that, use `.slice`:

```
var logoArray = logos.slice().reverse();
```